# Filter with ui-select Reversely

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

How can I filter the select options reversely?
I used `ui-select` for filtering my multi-select options. I can filter city based on country.
I want to add filtering country by city and tag the country name in the option.

Please take a look at this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hasarw/6f7v623g/12/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement this method to do this

```
$scope.getCityListByCity=function(){
      var sampletemp = [];
      $scope.selected.city.forEach(function(city) {
    var temp =  objectFromArrayFilter($scope.samples,'city',city);
    sampletemp = sampletemp.concat(temp);
            });
      $scope.uniquecountry = $filter('unique')(sampletemp, 'country');
        $scope.selected.country= [];

       $scope.country = $scope.uniquecountry.map(function(item) {
      return item.country
        })
      $scope.selected.country=$scope.country;

      if($scope.country.length == 0){

        $scope.uniquecountry = $filter('unique')($scope.samples, 'country');
    $scope.country = $scope.uniquecountry.map(function(item) {
      return item.country
    })
      }

    }
```

please refer this working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zxkhq6vg/1/) as per your requirement